# converting 'mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I've got a whole column of 1000+ entries in excel that has the date keyed in as '01/02, '01/03, '01/04... representing Jan 02, Jan 03, Jan 04 and so on as the person was trying to maintain a mm/dd format while saving on the column width.

This has become somewhat troublesome since the entries are all strings instead of dates and I need to input years in now to get dd/mm/yyyy.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this (other than of course manually changing each of the 1000+ entries?)

Also, I would appreciate it if you can share how I can possibly show dd/mm while retaining dd/mm/yyyy on the entry in excel?

Thank you so much for looking at this.

Comment: What have you tried?  I would suggest concatenating a separator and the year with the string, then convert it to a number (date).  You can custom format it to display however you want.

Comment: e.g. [here](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel) good tutotial for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 393 rows is not an excessive amount of data, you should find that bulk processing is much faster than looping through rows and processing each cell.

```
Sub Date_Conversion()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Columns(1)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 4), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3)
            .Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "mm/dd;;;[red]@"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

As no year was provided for any of the cells, the default is the current year. Any text value that was not processed will be formatted in a red font and left-aligned.

If you wanted to simply replace the existing data in column A, replace `.Offset(0, 4)` with `.Cells(1)`.

Comment: I was testing on a small insert to save time, but this really nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

In column 1 let's say you have the dd/mm.  In the next column, label that DD and in each cell put

```
=DAY(A2)
```

Where a2 is the target cell.  Do the same in the next column labelled MM.  Create another column labelled YYYY and put the year you want.  Then one last column labelled mm/dd/yyyy and put this formula

```
=CONCATENATE(D2&"/"&C2&"/"&B2)
```

Long work around, but will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date is represented by a string in the format mm/dd you need to first manipulate the string to get it in a day format:

You can use the below:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(CELL,2)&"/"&LEFT(CELL,2))
```

(replace cell with the address of the cell that you want to change(

Once you have done this to show dd/mm:
Select the cells that you want to format and:
Right Click / Format Cells / Custom 
and type in the inputbox dd/mm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this was really useful and pointed me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it and this charm of a code did the trick! Wanted to share with you guys!

```
Sub Date_Conversion()
For i = 1 To 393

m = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 1, 2)
D = Right(Cells(i, 1), 2)

Cells(i, 5).NumberFormat = "mm/dd;@"
Cells(i, 5) = DateSerial(2015, m, D)

Next

End Sub
```